# proof that the linear system obtained by interchanging two equations is equivalent to given system

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to write a mathematical proof for this elementary row operation but I don't know where to start. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Equivalent means that every solution of the first system is a solution of the second system and that the converse is also true. So prove this.

Comment: yes yes exactly