# proof that the linear system obtained by adding a multiple of an equation is equivalent to the given system

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Trying to write a mathematical proof for this elementary row operation. I don't know where to start though. Help!

Comment: Equivalent in the sense that the augmented matrices of the systems are equivalent? Or in the sense that the solutions don't change after the row operation?

Comment: the solutions don't change after the operation

Comment: Perhaps you should wait for answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2422537/265466), which is similar. The answer to that will likely show you where to start on this one, too.